# How can I change the default text color in Apple Mail 8.2?

Tags: macos, email

I want the default colour of my font I use to send emails using Mail 8.2 in Yosemite be blue.

Is it possible? If no, are their any easy work arounds?

Answer (score 1):

Click on the A in the right upper corner inside the new mail message you wish to compose.
That will bring up the text mark-up option, including colors.
So far I haven't seen an option in Yosemite to set this as default.